# How i can implement ARIMA model using Pyspark for purpose of forecasting?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, data-science, distributed-computing, databricks

I know we can implement the ARIMA model in spark but I am unable to find any good source to learn how I can implement the ARIMA model in Pyspark for purpose of forecasting or is there any other model that I can implement in SPARK for better performance. Please suggest me any good source for further research.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [this](https://github.com/sryza/spark-timeseries) open source package created by Sandy Ryza & Team

Ref- https://github.com/sryza/spark-timeseries/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/cloudera/sparkts/models/ARIMA.scala